# MySQL to PostgreSQL schema conversion

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to automatically convert my old MySQL table into PostgreSQL with help of the following [MySQL to PostgreSQL converter](http://www.convert-in.com/sql2pgs.htm)

Right now I don't understand or this tool is working correctly.

For example I have a following MySQL table:

**accepted_invitations**

with 2 Foreign Keys:

```
fk_accepted_invitations_invitation_id (accepted_invitations.invitation_id -> invitations.id)

fk_accepted_invitations_location_id (accepted_invitations.location_id -> locations.id)
```

and 2 Indexes:

```
PRIMARY(invitation_id)
fk_accepted_trial_invitations_location_id(location_id)
```

After converting in PostgreSQL I have a following table:

**accepted_invitations**

with 2 Constraints:

```
accepted_trial_invitations_pkey (PRIMARY KEY(invitation_id)) 
fk_accepted_trial_invitations_invitation_id (FOREIGN KEY(accepted_invitations.invitation_id -> invitations.id))
```

and 1 Index:

```
accepted_trial_invitations_location_id_idx  ON accepted_invitations USING btree (location_id);
```

I'm worried that after conversion I don't see Foreign Key in PostgreSQL for `fk_accepted_invitations_location_id`

Is it a converter error or this FK is redundant and should not be defined ?

Comment: Looking at the Postgres table it seems that the converter doesn't detect the `location_id` foreign key as an actual foreign key. This could be because MySQL foreign keys are not part of the field but implemented as constraints instead. You probably need to do some manual conversion in this case

Comment: Thanks for your answer